# Static / global variables in shared library in C language

Tags: c, process, shared-libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is global variable in a shared library / dll, shared across process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979303/is-global-variable-in-a-shared-library-dll-shared-across-process)

Hi stackoverflow,
I have just a little question about using .so in C programming.
I want to use static and global variables in a shared library.
If this library is loaded and used by several processes, will these processes share the global variables (i.e. will a process be able to modify variables used by an other process)?
Anyone got an idea about the behavior of these variables ?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979303/is-global-variable-in-a-shared-library-dll-shared-across-process

Answer (score 2):

> will these processes share the global variables

No.

Answer (score 1):

No, global variables are global inside a process. If you want to share data among processes you have to use specific IPC (inter-process communication) mechanisms.