# Why is my global variable (shared between a dll and an exe) not changing?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, global-variables

I am trying to share a global variable between `my_exe.exe` and `my_dll.dll`. I would expect changes to `my_var` made inside of `my_exe.cpp` to be reflected in `my_dll.cpp` at runtime. I expect the exe to have the dll loaded into it's address space and therefore making `my_var` shared between the 2. However changes made to `my_var` are not being reflected on either side. I am adding mydll.lib to the linker inputs for the my_exe project.
`my_exe.cpp`

```
extern __declspec(dllimport) float my_var;
typedef void (*called_from_exe)();

int main()
{
    HMODULE my_dll = LoadLibraryW("my_dll.dll");
    called_from_exe = (called_from_exe_t)GetProcAddress(my_dll, "called_from_exe");

   my_var = 7.f;
   called_from_exe();
}
```

`my_dll.cpp`

```
__declspec(dllexport) float my_var = 2.f;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void called_from_exe()
{
   print(my_var) // prints 0.00 instead of 7.00
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am linking against the .lib. I modified my post to indicate that.

Comment: You are not linking in the conventional sense when you dynamically load the library. I think you will find that you can write to my_var before loading the library. The only shared symbol in your address space is called_from_exe

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Is global variable in a shared library / dll, shared across process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979303/10871073). Especially the top-voted answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole My question only involves 1 process, which is `my_exe.exe`. The DLL is loaded into the address space of `my_exe.exe` and is part of it's address space once it's loaded.

Comment: @stark It looks like you're right. If I export/import the function by using `dllexport` and `dllimport` instead of `LoadLibrary` I can modify `my_var` inside of that function and the changes are reflected on both sides. Why is it different though? I thought those were just 2 different ways to do dynamic linking.

Comment: If you link to a library implicitly at the time you load your program (iusing dllimport as you say) then all exported symbols are shared.  If you load the library explicily at runtime (using LoadLibrary) then your symbols are already resolved to memory locations.  The only symbols from the DLL you can reference are ones you look up with GetProcAddress

Comment: Great answer, thank you!